# Python/Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'restaurants'

Tags: python, django

Following error trace is observed when python code is executed. 
Potential cause **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'restaurants'**

```
traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
      File "C:\Users\Archibald\Dev\trydjango1-11\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'restaurants'
```

Comment: Clearly, the module `restaurants` is not in the Python path but posting a traceback is not very helpful for people here. Maybe start your question with "I have a python app with the directory structure X and when I run Y I get the following traceback". It's very difficult for others to help you being outside of your computer without the proper context. Thanks and glad to help if you provide context about your application and environment.

Comment: Thanks, I am a beginner with sharing  code errors. I actually rolled back 2 an earlier commit to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When I checked setting.py , I saw I've forgot a comma. Seggust to go and check it..

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'home' , #This One was Missed
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

And also check where is restaurant folder it should be similar to:

```
project|
       |restaurant
       |project
```

not:

```
project|           
       |project|
               |restaurant
```