# Django ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django

I can't make a simple Django project work at all. I get the same error as listed in this question which I found:

[Python/Django =- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'restaurants'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126025/python-django-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-restaurants)

The only difference for me is that it says "No module named entries". This doesn't seem to have a resolution and I don't understand the comment on it either.

My directory structure is like this:

```
app
|- manage.py
|- app
    |- __init__.py
    |- entries
    |    |- __init__.py
    |    |- apps.py 
    |    |- models.py
    |    |- views.py
    |    |- admin.py
    |    |- tests.py
    |    |- migrations - __init__.py
    |    
    |- urls.py
    |- settings.py
    |- __pycache__
    |- wsgi.py
```

I have added the entries app to the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py. But from there it just seems to run into a problem.

I have been trying to work this out for ages and I just don't get it (even though it is probably easy).

UPDATE
This is the exact stacktrace I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/maximus/.virtualenvs/piglet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/maximus/.virtualenvs/piglet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/maximus/.virtualenvs/piglet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/maximus/.virtualenvs/piglet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/maximus/.virtualenvs/piglet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'entries'
```

Update 2:
This is my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'entries.apps.EntriesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I have tried using just entries as well. Which gives the same error.

Comment: Can you put the exact error with the stacktrace ? You code don't show where the error is happening.

Comment: I have updated to include the stacktrace. It doesn't really make sense to me, so hopefully you can shed some light.

Comment: you have to add your dir in the setting file [![settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq4to.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq4to.png)

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post to show you my INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py. I think I already have the app listed, so it shouldn't be that right?

Comment: I had this issue using Django in Visual Studio.  VS allows you to right click on any folder and add a new app so it's easy to add an app to the wrong folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your entries directory is in the wrong place.  You should move it up one level, so it's `app/entries` instead of `app/app/entries`.

(You are correct that 'entries.apps.EntriesConfig' is a valid way to add to INSTALLED_APPS.)

Comment: Hi, yeah I know that this is how it is laid out in the django tutorial. I was purposefully trying to put my apps inside the project for better structure. I thought this was possible, is it not possible?

Comment: You should stick with the directory structure with the tutorial if you are a beginner, or you will keep having these sort of difficulties.  The default directory structure is also probably a better structure than any structure that you will come up on your own as a beginner.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the people who wrote django do know better than me. It just doesn't sit right for some reason having all the apps sitting out there. I will just go forward with it the same as the tutorial for now. I shouldn't be so stubborn.

Comment: What works well is the pattern repository_root/django_root/ -- maybe you want another level of abstraction ABOVE your direcgtory structure.

Answer (score 5):

you should add the app in INSTALLED_APPS like so: `'app.entries'`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app.entries',
    'rest_framework', ]
```

Answer (score 4):

if you started a project using `django-admin startproject <project's name>` on terminal, then try not to change PROJECT_DIR and BASE_DIR. They should be same.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and I resolved that by moving the Django app folder into the Django project directory before I was able to run `python manage.py runserver` with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the INSTALLED_APPS should be
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'app.entries.apps.EntriesConfig',
   .......
]

Also in entries/apps.py file in  fEntriesConfig() set 
name = 'app.entries'

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the simplest mistake, which is often the hardest to see:
I missed the **comma separation** between the new app I wanted to add in the INSTALLED_APPS.
Dont be me, double check your spelling.

Answer (score -3):

its seems to be error which i faced during this  django jounrney
you have to do here manage.py and firstproject whatever the name at the same direcotry then add new "fist_App" in the setting.py at installed_App list then
check the *python manage.py fristapp*