# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce' for Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

So I get the following error: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce'`
when trying to deploy my Django app to Azure. It works perfectly when I test it locally, but breaks down on Azure.

I've already done a pip freeze > requirements.txt and verified that django-tinymce is on that list, I've restarted my server and re-synced my GitHub project. TinyMce has been added to INSTALLED_APPS already.

Here are a few code parts along with the error:

settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'cpu',
    'django_cron',
    'tinymce',

]
#...
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    }
```

Error from Azure:

```sh
[2019-10-29 11:27:45 +0000] [44] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252815138Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252820439Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252824939Z     worker.init_process()
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252837239Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252841739Z     self.load_wsgi()
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252845439Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252849239Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252852939Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252856839Z     self.callable = self.load()
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252860539Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252864339Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252868039Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252871939Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252875739Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252879539Z     __import__(module)
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252883139Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/pcbuilder/wsgi.py", line 16, in 
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252887439Z     application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252891139Z   File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252894939Z     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252898639Z   File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252902539Z     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252906239Z   File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252910039Z     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252914039Z   File "/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252918039Z     module = import_module(entry)
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252921639Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252925539Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-10-29T11:27:45.252929339Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce'
```

pip freeze:

```
astroid==2.3.1
beautifulsoup4==4.8.1
bs4==0.0.1
colorama==0.4.1
Django==2.2.6
django-background-tasks==1.2.0
django-classy-tags==0.9.0
django-cms==3.7.0
django-common-helpers==0.9.2
django-compat==1.0.15
django-cron==0.5.1
django-formtools==2.1
django-sekizai==1.0.0
django-tinymce==2.8.0
django-treebeard==4.3
djangocms-admin-style==1.4.0
djangocms-attributes-field==1.1.0
djangocms-icon==1.4.1
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.2
mccabe==0.6.1
mysql==0.0.2
mysql-connector-python==8.0.18
mysqlclient==1.4.4
protobuf==3.10.0
pylint==2.4.2
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pytz==2019.3
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.9.4
sqlparse==0.3.0
style==1.1.0
update==0.0.1
urllib3==1.25.6
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Comment: What is your deployment process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362122/django-modulenotfounderror)

Comment: @absolutelydevastated I commit my changes to GitHub master, then I wait for Azure to re-deploy. It just processes the changes. I've had success before with Azure updating pip based on my requirements.txt, so I don't know why this issue is happening.

Comment: did you try doing `pip install -r requirements.txt` manually?

Comment: @SamCreamer yes I did

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to make it work. I'm guessing that when I had the import `from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE` Azure didn't like that, so I removed it, and made my model with the HTMLField() from TinyMCE.

This is my TinyMCE import in models.py: `from tinymce import models as tinymce_models`