# django.setup() giving me ModuleNotFoundError: when ran in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

I have setup a django project and an app for that project as per below.
After I changed the model I am able to makemigration and migrate.
I can run the server and the admin page displays my app as expected.
I am able to run python manage.py shell, import and manipulate my models in the shell.

However when I try to import my model from another python file (in pycharm) I am getting an error stating that the module for my app cannot be found.

OS:

```
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia
Release:    19.3
Codename:   tricia
```

IDE

```
PyCharm 2020.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-202.7660.27, built on October 6, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.34 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1871M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: Statistic, com.alayouni.ansiHighlight, com.intellij.ideolog, org.toml.lang, ru.meanmail.plugin.requirements, com.jetbrains.plugins.ini4idea
Current Desktop: X-Cinnamon
```

Python:

```
python 3.6
```

Django

```
Django==3.1.3
```

I have read the previous related question: [django-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-restaurants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126025/python-django-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-restaurants) and [django-modulenotfounderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362122/django-modulenotfounderror) but I think my issue is somewhat different.

I have not moved files around or change folder names, I really tried to keep it as per the tutorial as possible (I even recreate the exat poll app example from django doc and got the same error).

I guess this has to do with my environment variables not set properly but I am quite novice in all this and I do not fully know understand what I am supposed to check, how am I suppose to check these and finally how these can be fixed. So I would really appreciate a detailed answer if the issue is related to the environment variables. Thank you!

In pycharm I have several repos used for that project that are saved in a folder and I usually open that folder containing all the repos in pycharm.
The repo of interest here is called **'static_data'** and it contains the follwing tree:

```
├── backend
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── static_data_app
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── tools
│   │   │   ├── loading.py
│   │   │   ├── new_expiry.py
│   │   │   └── setup.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── static_data_project
│       ├── asgi.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
├── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── test.py
```

I have setup
static_data_project/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'static_data_app.apps.StaticDataAppConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Then when I try to run static_data/test.py in pycharm, which has the following code in it:

```
import os
import sys
import django

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'static_data.backend.static_data_project.settings'
django.setup()

from static_data.backend.static_data_app.models import Asset

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = list(Asset.objects.all())
    print(my_list)
```

this is what I got
(reminder that in pycharm, I have all my repos in a certain folder and that repo of interest here is called **'static_data'**)

```
/home/[...]/env/bin/python3.6 /home/[...]/static_data/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[...]/static_data/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/[...]/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/[...]/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/[...]/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'static_data_app'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find it a lot easier if you have your imports relative to the project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`)

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'static_data_project.settings'
django.setup()

from static_data_app.models import Asset
```

If you move the `test.py` file into the project directory, I think that should work. If you keep the `test.py` file where it is, then you need to add the project directory to the Python path before you call `django.setup()`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/backend')
```

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot!
backend is in a repo called static_data which is inside a fodler 'workspace' containing other repos I also use. I was adding '/path/to/workspace' to sys.path, I thought that would work (since backend is inside static_data which is inside workspace) but it doesn't and I did not think about adding just the path to backend (I do not fully understand how sys.path works).

Comment: side question on the import relative to the project: my IDE (pycharm) is complaining (just highlighting in red, no big deal) when I do it this way. It does prevent me from running the program or anything but I am just curious to know whether there is something I should do to stop pycharm from complaining about it?

Comment: `sys.path.append('/path/to/backend')` is adding the `backend` directory to the Python path. When you do (say) `from static_data_app.models import Asset`, Python will search all the directories in the Python path, and find the `static_data_app` module in the `backend` directory.

Comment: You should be able to configure the Python path for your project in PyCharm to include the `backend` directory, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: *I was adding '/path/to/workspace' to sys.path, I thought that would work* - Lots of your Django code assumes that the project directory is on the Python path. For example, the error in your traceback is caused when Django tries to load `static_data_app.apps.StaticDataAppConfig` from your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: That works: I have added backend to the Interpreter Paths in pycharm and it is no longer complaining. Thanks!

On the other point: if I have this tree: workspace/static_data/backend/static_data_app does it mean that Python will not be able to search recursively and that's why adding workspace to sys.path does not work and I need to add backend instead?

Comment: If the `workspace` is on the Python path, and you try `import static_data_app`, then Python will only search the workspace directory for the `static_data_app` module. It won't search `workspace/static_data` or `workspace/static_data/backend`.